# Scapy - Creating a packet and showing it leads to >NoneType object has no attribute 'route'<

Tags: python, exception, import, scapy, nonetype

I have just discovered something curious.
Doing the following

```
>>> from scapy.layers.inet import Ether,IP,UDP
>>> e=Ether()
>>> i=IP()
>>> u=UDP()
>>> p=e/i/u
>>> p.show()
```

results in this error

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py", line 838, in show
    reprval = f.i2repr(self,fvalue)
  File "/home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/fields.py", line 191, in i2repr
    x = self.i2h(pkt, x)
  File "/home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 89, in i2h
    x = conf.neighbor.resolve(pkt,pkt.payload)
  File "/home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 38, in resolve
    return self.resolvers[k](l2inst,l3inst)
  File "/home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 732, in <lambda>
    conf.neighbor.register_l3(Ether, IP, lambda l2,l3: getmacbyip(l3.dst))
  File "/home/lk/virtualenvs/FuzzingEnv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/layers/l2.py", line 57, in getmacbyip
    iff,a,gw = conf.route.route(ip)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'route'
>>> ...
```

But just importing everything from scapy right afer the error like this

```
>>> ...
>>> from scapy.all import *
WARNING: No route found for IPv6 destination :: (no default route?)
>>> p.show()
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst       = ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  src       = 00:00:00:00:00:00
  type      = 0x800
###[ IP ]###
     version   = 4
     ihl       = None
     tos       = 0x0
     len       = None
     id        = 1
     flags     = 
     frag      = 0
     ttl       = 64
     proto     = udp
     chksum    = None
     src       = 127.0.0.1
     dst       = 127.0.0.1
     \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
        sport     = domain
        dport     = domain
        len       = None
        chksum    = None
>>>
```

somehow seems to fix it. How can this be? Is there some special module I need to import?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import scapy route module as well.

```
from scapy import route
from scapy.layers.inet import Ether,IP,UDP
e=Ether()
i=IP()
u=UDP()
p=e/i/u
p.show()
```